# can anyone help me "mount fail"

Tags: mount

[image]

help me please.
[+]-Linux only without windows

Comment: Depending on the data importance, you can try to recover it using `ddrescue`.  If the data is of extreme importance you should determine your level of comfort and potentially look to a service to restore the information.  More information here... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: I this Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your hard disk is on the way to die. Don't try anything, take it to a professional to recover the still readable data from it!